# Desde un activity "A" abrir activity "B" y después una "C", y que al regresar hasta la "A" los datos de la activity "A" sigan intactos

Tags: android-studio, activity

Tengo una activity "A" en la cual el usuario introduce datos y necesito abrir una activity "B" para que desde la activity "B" abra una activity "C" y seleccione ciertos datos, entonces se le tiene que regresar a la activity "B" y después a la activity "A".
El problema surge cuando en la activity "B" abro la activity "C" y regreso hasta la activity "A" ya que todos los datos de esta se borran y necesito que sigan. Esto no me ocurre si abro la activity "B" solamente y regreso a la "A"
  La unica forma que se me ocurre es que al abrir el activity "B" desde "A" ejecutar onPause() y que al abrir la activity "C" desde la "B" también ejecutarlo, pero no funciona.

**¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?**

Comment: Humberto, esto depende de varios factores: si la configuración del dispositivo de los usuarios siempre destruye las activities. Si las activities B y C demandan memoria el sistema operativo puede destruir Activity A. Aporta más detalles de como realizas el Intent de una a otra Activitie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el manejo del ciclo de vida de un activity esta a cargo del Sistema Operativo, por lo que no podes confiar en que una Activity siga vivo cuando en pantalla se esta mostrando otro Activity.

Para resolver el problema del pasaje de datos existen varias soluciones, la mejor es usar `startActivityForResult`. Es una tecnica muy buena para atrapar los datos del resultado de la ejecucion de un activity. Por ejemplo cuando lanzas el Activity de la camara de fotos se utiliza este patron.

En tu caso podrias usarla haciendo que el `ActivityA` lance al `ActivityB` con `startActivityForResult` y a su vez `ActivityB` ejecuta al `ActivityC` con otro `startActivityForResult`.

Asi es como podes ejecutar el ActivityB desde el ActivityA

```
void startActivityB(){
   Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
   startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}
```

Esto tambien lo pones en el ActiviA para escuchar la respuesta del ActiviB.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == 1) {
      if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
         String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); //Suponiendo que es un String lo que esperas recibir
      }
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //Este seria el camino por el cual no hay datos que retornar. Manejalo como mas te guste.
      }
   }
}
```

Asi es como en el ActivityB seteas los datos a devolver para el ActivityA

```
void returnData(String result){
   Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
   returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);// result en este caso es la variable que contiene los datos a devolver, pero podes agregar tantos Extra como te hagan falta.
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
   finish();
}
```

Esto mismo lo podes hacer con el ActivityB y ActivityC para que uno le retorne datos al otro.

---

Otra forma un poco mas rustica podria ser guardando los datos en algun otro lado, por ejemplo en la `SharedPreference` o como propiedades de la clase `Application`, la cual podes extender, esta ademas, permanecera en memoria hasta que la app se cierre, aun asi, siempre que sea posible es mejor usar la primer opcion.